# How to know which List is concerned in a selectionChanged if there are more than one Lists?

Tags: lwuit

There are many `List` in my Form and they all call `addSelectionListener`. The problem is that the parameters of the abstract method `selectionChanged` are just `(int oldSelected, int newSelected)` ! So how to know which `List` was clicked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use separate Listeners (one for each list)?

Comment: Additional idea to eventually fit your needs:
Call one a universal methode from all listeners with an additional parameter for identification of the event source.